# Unspecified error MySQL function & Delphi

Tags: mysql, sql, function, delphi, delphi-xe3

I try to call to a MySQL function in Delphi but i can't I have `Unspecified error.`.

sample function 1 is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `TEST`(`test` INT)
    RETURNS INT
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    RETURN 123+TEST ;
END
```

an other sample of SQL function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `GET_OPTION_AS_INT`(`id` INT)
    RETURNS bigint(20)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT 'GET option value'
BEGIN
    RETURN CAST((SELECT `option_value` FROM `OPTION` WHERE `option_id` = `id`) AS UNSIGNED); 
END
```

My Delphi code is:

```
  qry1.Close;
  qry1.SQL.Clear;
  qry1.SQL.Add('SELECT `TEST`(:test)');
  qry1.Parameters.ParamByName('test').Value := 1 ;
  qry1.Open;
```

second Delphi code:

```
  qry1.Close;
  qry1.SQL.Clear;
  qry1.SQL.Add('SELECT GET_OPTION_AS_INT(:id)');
  qry1.Parameters.ParamByName('id').Value := 1 ;
  qry1.Open;
```

This a an simple example otherwise I test with other function same as `GET_OPTION_VALUE` and ...

How I can fix it?

Comment: Hard to say. But back to your problem; why are you enclosing function name into quotes in your query ? I'm not keen on MySQL, but aren't those quotes used (primarily ?) for constant string values ? Shouldn't that be just `SELECT TEST(:test)` ? Have you tried to run the statement in a DB management app anyway ?

Comment: because the mysql know internal values same as table_name colum_name or function_name with those quotes, and i test without quotes.same as `SELECT GET_OPTION_AS_INT(:id)`, yes I test with `Heidi SQL` it's worked good and I copied sql from that.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it is irrelevant if this is a function or a select statement.
The Parameter :test does not get created by simply assigning some text to qry1.SQL.

Check out your functions by using

```
  qry1.Close;
  qry1.SQL.Clear;
  qry1.SQL.Add('SELECT TEST(1)');
  qry1.Open;
```

If you create the query at design time then set the parameter types in the visual SQL Query object ParamByName will work.

There is no point in creating SQL on the fly using parameters as you know at that point what the parameter values will be anyway...

Comment: `Unspecified error` again, I'm test it before ask question.